# How to force Type3 fonts?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

A bit unusual question, because most Type3-related questions ask for the opposite, avoiding the use of rasterized fonts.

However I am experimenting with fonts and PDF Forms, and I would like to use rasterized fonts for a test. How to achieve that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your example with `\pdfmapfile{}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can suppress the loading of the map-file and so force bitmap fonts with

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapfile{}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```